# Selecting the proper .scaleMode **and** HStack

Tags: swiftui, hstack, autoscalemode

The focus here is selecting the proper `.scaleMode`.

Please note that the graphics will be greatly enhanced in the next couple of weeks. But in the meantime, I thought I'd concentrate on the coding.

**===== EDIT ======**

I have decided to focus on using `HStack` by adding it to my `GameScene` code with this:

Note that my `struct` is just defined here .. it is instantiated via `_ = StaticObjects()` within `func didMove(..)`

As explained further down, this declaration is at the very top of `class GameScene`. The following declaration just defines it as a var within our `class GameScene: SKScene`

What is a big mystery to me if how the HStack is actually drawn?  It's placed within the `class GameScene', but somehow I do not put in the code required to draw it within my` GameScene`.

```
class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {
    
    struct StaticObjects: View {
        
        var body: some View {
            
#if os(iOS)
            let imageFolder = "images_iOS/"
#elseif os(tvOS)
            let imageFolder = "images_tvOS/"
#endif
            let theBuildings: [String] = [imageFolder + "hotel",
                                          imageFolder + "saloon",
                                          imageFolder + "watertower",
                                          imageFolder + "jail",
                                          imageFolder + "farmhouse",
                                          imageFolder + "barn"]
            
            let theFigures: [String] = [imageFolder + "desperado",
                                        imageFolder + "sheriff",
                                        imageFolder + "horse",
                                        imageFolder + "guy"]
            
            HStack(alignment: .bottom) {
                
                // “Initializer 'init(_:rowContent:)' requires that
                // ‘SomeType’ conform to 'Identifiable’”
                //
                // Using a List or ForEach on primitive types that don’t
                // conform to the Identifiable protocol, such as an array
                // of strings or integers.
                ForEach(theBuildings, id: \.self) { theBuilding in
                    Image(theBuilding)
                        .resizable()
                        .scaledToFit()
                        .zIndex(2)
                    Spacer()
                }   // ForEach

            }   // HStack
                        
            HStack(alignment: .bottom) {
                
                ForEach(theFigures, id: \.self) { theFigure in
                    Image(theFigure)
                        .resizable()
                        .scaledToFit()
                        .offset(x: 0.0, y: -15.0)
                        .zIndex(2)
                    Spacer()
                }   // ForEach

            }   // HStack
            
        }   // body:
        
    }   // struct

    
    override func sceneDidLoad() {
        
        super.sceneDidLoad()
                                   
     }   // sceneDidLoad
    
    
    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
       
        super.didMove(to:view)
        
        physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self

        _ = StaticObjects()   // instantiate my struct

                             
    }   // didMove
    
    
    func didBegin(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
                                

    }   // didBegin
    
}   // class GameScene
```

Unfortunately, I must still be doing something that is basically wrong.

**For example, am I placing this `struct`in the right place (= `GameScene`?)**

**===== end EDIT =====**

Using `.resizeFill` shows this for portrait view:

[image]

Using `.resizeFill` shows this for landscape view:

[image]

Please note that for the landscape view, the line of `SKSpriteNodes` (**and** the railroad tracks) got greatly inset which is unsatisfactory. In the portrait view, this line + tracks are spread out edge-to-edge horizontally which is what I'd like to happen also in the landscape view

I then tried `.aspectFill`. This `.scaleMode` did eliminate the above mentioned inset which is **great**. But, as expected, in each case, portrait + landscape, the top-most Status Light (`SKShapeNode`) got clipped.

So, how do I get the best of both worlds = **no** clipping of the Status Light and **no** inset of the `SKSpriteNodes`??

Please note that the line of `SKSpriteNodes` are graphically added to the GameScene's `.sks` file. The railroad tracks, the train + dog are dynamically added with Swift coding because the train + dog move along the tracks **and** these tracks are the `UIBezierPath` along which the train + dog move.